# "lets take this to chat" before being prompted

Tags: discussion

I have seen a prompt that will create a link to take some users to a chat room to discuss something if they make a few comments back and forth.

My question is: Is there anywhere to find a link that does the same thing, before that prompt is shown? So If I know I am likely to have a bunch of questions for the OP I can post a chat invite link first rather than doing comments back and forth until it shows up?

I've clicked over to chat and I found where I can create a room but it seems to be intended for a more public and less specific topic than what would be used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can really do currently is to create a new room and then invite the user to that room. You can also leave a link to the room as a comment on their post if you want. The automated chat link will also create a public room, so from that regard it's essentially the same (and you can give it whatever title you want).

One downside is that the auto-inserted link will import the comments from the post into the chat room when it's created. Creating your own room beforehand will not do this, but if you are pre-emptively setting up a chat with someone then there is likely not going to be a long comment thread to import anyway, I'd imagine.

This has also been discussed [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted).

Answer (score 5):

You can also just write the user on the Android chat room with `@<username>` or `username:`, even if the user is not in the room he will get a notification in the top bar (AFAIK).

Comment: This works, too, with the caveat that `"you can only mention @someone who has been in the room at some point."` (from the [chat FAQ](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications)).